# Mysqli procedural: how to perform a query to retrieve different possible values from the same field?

Tags: mysqli

The following snippet is ok. It gives a good result when the field is not empty.

```
$p_tag = '';

$query_pre = mysqli_prepare($bdd, 'SELECT  min , comments , p_tag , p_name  FROM pictures WHERE  tag != ? ');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query_pre, "s", $p_tag);    

mysqli_stmt_execute($query_pre); 

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query_pre, $data['mini'], $data['comments'], $data['p_tag'] , $data['p_name']);
```

**I would like to refine the search and retrieve results when the *tag field* contains 'father'  or  'mother'  or  'brother' or 'sister' or 'aunt' or 'uncle' ect ...** ( but not friend , colleague ...)

I am new to `Mysqli` and it seems to be so less flexible than `Mysql` that I cannot figure out how to perform what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you could just change your query to select only results with those values.

```
SELECT  min , comments , p_tag , p_name  FROM pictures WHERE  tag in ('father','mother','brother','sister','aunt','uncle')
```

Comment: First test seems to work ok ! I had never come across that query syntax up to now. There is so little to be found about Mysqli. I am interested in any documentation other than php manual. Thanks a lot !

Comment: That's just mysql syntax. It's not different for mysql, mysqli, or PDO. I think of IN as standing for includes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in